# Script to write contents of incoming outlook messages to file

Tags: outlook, scripting

Hi I'd like to automatically write incoming outlook messages to a text-file on the drive. How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty. The easiest way is likely with an Outlook Add-in, although you could use MAPI directly.

I would start here: http://www.outlookcode.com